# When is the onecolumn document class option explicitly required?

Tags: document-classes, class-options

Is there any situation while writing LaTeX documents where we need to explicitly specify the `oneside` document class option?

For example, the `oneside` option in the following code is redundant because `article` uses `oneside` by default, anyway:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In placerat
erat augue, a sodales nunc rhoncus sit amet.
\end{document}
```

The `proc` class uses a two-column layout, so `onecolumn` as a supported option would have made sense but attempting to use `onecolumn` with `proc` leads to the following error:

```
! Class proc Error: Option `onecolumn' not supported.
```

So what then is a valid scenario where we explicitly need to specify the `onecolumn` option?

Comment: when you are using a class that defaults to twocolumn and supports a user option to use one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you know any such document class in TeX Live that I can use to test this?

Comment: no:-) it would be trivial to make one though, just load article class passing twocolumn by default

Comment: IEEEtran defaults to twocolumn but supports onecolumn (preview).